# Access is Denied on Anaconda Prompt - Cannot Use Conda Activate

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I was having some problems with Anaconda on my work computer, and I needed to uninstall and reinstall it. After we uninstalled it, I deleted some left over folders that were not initially deleted. In particular, I deleted:

- C:\Users\MY_ID.anaconda,
- C:\Users\MY_ID.conda,
- C:\Users\MY_ID.ipython,
- C:\Users\MY_ID.keras,
- C:\Users\MY_ID.matplotlib,
- C:\Users\MY_ID.spyder-py3,
- C:\Users\MY_ID\AppData\Local\conda,
- C:\Users\MY_ID\AppData\Local\Spyder.

After deleting those folders, we began the installation process. During installation, we had the following settings:

- Add Anaconda to PATH,
- All Users,
- Changed the directory from C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3 to C:\Users\My_ID\Anaconda3.

Once the installation was complete, I was able to open Anaconda Prompt and use the **conda** command to activate my virtual environment and install packages from within that environment.

At the end of the day, I restarted my computer. This morning, I opened the Anaconda Prompt, and I receive:

**Access is denied.**
**C:\Users\MY_ID> _**

How come it suddenly quit working? Do I need to clear caches? Also, I do not have Admin Privileges. Thank you!

Comment: **Opinion:** Conda is seriously much less of a hassle if you don't add it to `PATH` (often leads to environment leakage) and don't install for **All Users** (often leads to permissions issues). And since you're reinstalling anyway, install Miniconda instead, and never install anything in **base** (other than the occasionally `conda update conda`), but instead make new envs for each project.

Comment: Hi, merv! Thank you for the response. So, do you recommend reinstalling Anaconda again with the Add Anaconda to PATH unchecked and Just Me checked? Also, we only have access to the Anaconda3-2018.12-Windows-x86-64.exe at the time. We'll have to get Miniconda approved. When I installed Anaconda this last time, I created a new virtual environment. That's always the first thing I do when installing new packages.

Comment: Yeah, if you have to do Anaconda then yes, those options. And yeah keep up the good practice on creating new envs!

Comment: Sounds good, merv :) Thanks for your help.